# Transformation Failing due to xsl:include

Tags: java, xslt

I have a Java maven project which includes XSLT transformations. I load the stylesheet as follows:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();

dFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
java.io.InputStream in = cl.getResourceAsStream("xsl/stylesheet.xsl");

InputSource xslInputSource = new InputSource(in);
Document xslDoc = dBuilder.parse(xslInputSource);

DOMSource xslDomSource = new DOMSource(xslDoc);

Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslDomSource);
```

The stylesheet.xsl has a number of  statements. These appear to be causing problems, when I try to run my unit tests I get the following errors:

```
C:\Code\workspace\app\dummy.xsl; Line #0; Column #0; Had IO Exception with stylesheet file: footer.xsl
C:\Code\workspace\app\dummy.xsl; Line #0; Column #0; Had IO Exception with stylesheet file: topbar.xsl
```

The include statements in the XSLT are relative links

```
xsl:include href="footer.xsl"
xsl:include href="topbar.xsl"
```

I have tried experimenting and changing these to the following - but I still get the error.

```
xsl:include href="xsl/footer.xsl"
xsl:include href="xsl/topbar.xsl"
```

Any ideas? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved my problem using a URIResolver.

```
class MyURIResolver implements URIResolver {
@Override
public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
  try {
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    java.io.InputStream in = cl.getResourceAsStream("xsl/" + href);
    InputSource xslInputSource = new InputSource(in);
    Document xslDoc = dBuilder.parse(xslInputSource);
    DOMSource xslDomSource = new DOMSource(xslDoc);
    xslDomSource.setSystemId("xsl/" + href);
    return xslDomSource;
 } catch (...
```

And assigning this with the TransformerFactory

```
tFactory.setURIResolver(new MyURIResolver());
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)`. Failing to do so may prevent the parent stylesheet to load whatever template is in your child stylesheet, resulting in ElemTemplateElement errors.

Comment: Beware, setURIResolver can be set on the transformer too (i.e. instead of the factory), but it has no effect then.

Answer (score 11):

URIResolver can also be used in a more straightforward way as below:

```
class XsltURIResolver implements URIResolver {

    @Override
    public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
        try{
              InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xslts/" + href);
              return new StreamSource(inputStream);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Use the URIResolver with TransformerFactory as shown below:

```
TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transFact.setURIResolver(new XsltURIResolver());
```

Or with a lambda expression:

```
transFact.setURIResolver((href, base) -> {
    final InputStream s = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xslts/" + href);
    return new StreamSource(s);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your DocumentBuilder object with an [EntityResolver](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html).

You'll have to extend EntityResolver class to resolve your external entities (footer.xsl and topbar.xsl).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this once with relative paths in the XSLT.

If you can, try to put absolute paths in the XSLT - that should resolve the error.

An absolute path probably isn't preferable for the final version of the XSLT, but it should get you past the maven problem. Perhaps you can have two versions of the XSLT, one with absolute paths for maven and one with relative paths for whatever other tool it's being used with.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for the reply - this does fix the problem. However, the stylesheets are included in the jar file and so this solution would not work once the whole thing is packaged up.